# how to pick a column with a value in a given row, remove it and continue to next row doing the same in r

Tags: r, dataframe, iteration, filtering

I have a dataframe of correlations between cases and controls. Some of these are perfect correlations based on their demographics, (ie they have the exact same combination of demographic values) and thus contain a value of 1.0

The cases are rows, the controls columns. I would like to select 20 controls that demographically match my 20 cases.

Iterating from one row to the next, I would like to extract the first column that contains the value 1.0 for that row (ie the control is a perfect demographic match for that case).  Then i would like to REMOVE this column and proceed to the next row, so that if it contained a value of 1 in multiple rows, I wouldnt get it returned over and over again.

The end result im hoping for would be a list of 20 unique columns (controls), each a perfect match to one of my 20 rows (cases).

I feel like there should be a simple way to do this. Can anyone help?

Comment: I think this would be clearer with a minimal example, maybe just a few columns and rows, ideally as code so we can run it and test out potential solutions. I don't understand how you are iterating through rows to remove columns.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. Posting in case anyone else has this problem. If you have a correlation matrix between samples and controls with values of 1.0 in it (perfect matches), and just want to extract a non-redundant names list comprised of one matching control for each case this should work:

```
corout<- cor(cases,controls)

corout <-as.data.frame(t(corout))

df2 <- as.data.frame(Filter(function(x) any(x == 1), corout))
temp <- apply(df2, 2, function(x) names(which(x == 1)))
temp.b<-as.data.frame(unlist(temp))

v <-vector()

for(i in temp){
    matching_control <- as.vector(str_split(as.vector(i), " "))
    
    for (j in 1:length(matching_control )) { 
        
        
        if((is.element(matching_control[j], v))){  
            
        } else 
            
            if(!is.element(matching_control[j], v)){ 
                v <-append(v, matching_control[j]) 
                break
                
                
            }    
    }
    
}


selected.matches <-unlist(v)
rm(v)
```

Comment: reiterating what Jon Spring said, this answer would be a lot better with a sample input

Comment: you can use dput()